# How to differentiate between overloads when an argument is null

Tags: c#

This seems like something that I should have thought about before now, but it itn't. It also seems like there should be an existing way to do this.

The problem: Say I have a class with a couple of constructors

```
public class ModuleAction
{
    public ModuleAction(string url, string caption)
    { ... }

    public ModuleAction(string url, ModuleAction action)
    { ... }
}
```

And then elsewhere, I make a call to one of those constructors, but the second argument is null, it does not know which constructor to use

```
ModuleAction action = new ModuleAction("http://google.co.uk", null);
```

Is there any way of doing this? My current solution is to add an unused argument to one of the constructors, but that doesn't seem right.

My solution: (not pretty)

```
public class ModuleAction
{
    public ModuleAction(string url, string caption, bool unused)
    { ... }

    public ModuleAction(string url, ModuleAction action)
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: If you pass null then it shouldn't matter which constructor gets called, because you're only passing the url.

Comment: You can cast the null to be the appropriate type.

Comment: well, I would simply use an empty string instead of null

Comment: @NoPyGod: absolutely not true!!  The first overload might use an empty caption instead of a default; the second might use no action instead of a default.  You could code so that what you say is true, but you absolutely can't assume it!

Comment: @TheWaxMann: can you create a new constructor overload with only one parameter?

Comment: @DanPuzey I think it's a poor practice to be differentiating between different constructors based on the type of a null value. I think a static method would be better in this situation.. ie.. ModuleAction.CreateWithCaption(string url, string caption)

Comment: @DanPuzey I could indeed create a new constructor with only 1 argument, I hadn't considered that either. One of the constructors does use the null value in the code though, I suppose I could just make it a default for the new constructor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several options here.

The simple, direct solution is to cast the `null` to they type of the argument in the overload you wish to use:

```
ModuleAction action = new ModuleAction("http://google.co.uk", (string)null);
```

A better option would be to use a new constructor that has a single parameter and to chain it, using defaults:

```
public ModuleAction(string url) : this(url, "")
```

Comment: This answer is the essence of the first three comments ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Good thing it predates two of those ;)

Comment: @Oded Thanks, I didn't know you could cast a null value. I have used chaining before, but didn't know you could use the format you have used for it. What version of .net did that come in?

Comment: Just had a further thought about this, when I call `this(url, null)` it still will not know which one I am trying to use, so do I still need to cast the null ie `this(url, (ModuleAction)null)`

Comment: @TheWaxMann - but with an overload, you just use `this(url)`.

Comment: @TheWaxMann - Chaining existed from v2.0, I believe.

Comment: I meant in the chained constructor ie `public ModuleAction(string url) : this(url, null)` How will that know which of the 2 other constructors to use? (the null is an important value in one of the constructors)

Comment: @TheWaxMann - Did you see what I used - an empty string. Don't use `null` - be explicit.

Answer (score 6):

You can cast null to expected parameter type.

```
new ModuleAction(url, (string) null);

new ModuleAction(url, (ModuleAction) null);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use casting for this:

```
new ModuleAction("http://google.co.uk", (ModuleAction)null);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have three options:

1. You can cast the null to be the appropriate type.
2. You can provide a constructor that only takes one argument and use that instead of passing null.
3. You can use named parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Constructor which will not have the second argument.

```
public ModuleAction(string url) 
{ ... }
```

Then it's clear which one will be used if 2nd argument cannot be supplied.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
new ModuleAction("uu", (string)null);
new ModuleAction("uu", (ModuleAction)null);
```

?